# Enforcing different C++ template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I'm try to create a BidirectionalMap class using (only) STL (no, boost is not an option.) I have 99% percent of it working the way that I want, but what I really can't figure out is how to force the template to require two different types so that operator[] can be properly overridden. Something like...

```
template < class KeyType, class ValueType >
class BidirectionalMap
{
  public:

  ...

  const ValueType& operator[](const KeyType& _k ) { return( m_keyMap[ _k ] ); }
  const KeyType& operator[](const ValueType& _v ) { return( m_valMap[ _v ] ); }

  private:

  std::map< KeyType > m_keyMap;
  std::map< ValueType > m_valueMap;
};

main()
{
  BidirectionalMap< Foo, Foo > fooMap; // won't work, ambiguous.
  BidirectionalMap< Foo, Bar > fooBarMap; // does work.
}
```

Thoughts?
-R

Comment: Won't C++ handle this out of the box for you? Since your `operator[]` will be amigious I guess compile will fail if `KeyType` and `ValueType` is equal.

Comment: You can take a look at the source for `boost::multi_index_container` to get some hints I think.  You can't legally copy their code verbatim without meeting the license requirements, but you can at least see how they did it.

Comment: It already requires distinct types. Providing the same type for both parameters would attempt to create two different versions of the same method `operator[]` and thus fail to compile. What more do you want to achieve?

Comment: `**int** main()` should it be.

Comment: You could use some SFINAE techniques to ensure that the two template parameters are different, but really, why would you be so restrictive? That's a fairly poor concept of a bimap if it has such an arbitrary constraint. Maybe you should really take a look at Boost's version and implement the bimap as a `std::set` of relations?!

Answer (score 15):

Just add the following partial specialisation:

```
template <typename T>
class BidirectionalMap<T, T>;
```

This will case the compiler to instantiate a template that isn’t defined (since the above is only declared) and bail if the user tries to pass the same type as both template arguments.

Comment: Be sure to put a helpful comment below that declaration, that explains to the user what they did wrong. This is essentially their error-message.

Comment: Or maybe an implementation with a static_assert.

Comment: Yeah, put a basic constructor in with a static assert of `false` and a suitable error message...

Answer (score 6):

Of course the real question is: *Why such an arbitrary restriction ?*

I would consider perfectly normal to have the same type as key and value, so instead of providing an ambiguous operator overload, perhaps could you simply provide two different methods ?

```
ValueType const& by_key(KeyType const&) const;
KeyType const& by_value(ValueType const&) const;
```

and be done with it.

**EDIT**: Following @Georg Fritzsche's remark :)

Remember that one of the paramount rules of overloading is that all overloads should have the same basic meaning.

Comment: I'd much prefer a solution similar to this - it's not only less restrictive but also leads to less surprises when reading/debugging ("wait, what was the type of that temporary again?").

Comment: @Georg: indeed, I have edited the answer to make it explicit. All overloads should have the same meaning / perform (roughly) the same operation, else it becomes difficult for the reader to understand what's going on.